# How to add repeatable sections like Header,Footer with all page classes of an application to page object model with selenium and java?

Tags: java, selenium, header, pom.xml, footer

I am trying to automate web tests using Selenium and JAVA,

I have a web application with certain sections like header and footer repeating across multiple pages. I am using page object model, creating page class file for each web page. All the web pages have same header and footer.

I  have created two page class files, HomePage.java and SmallBusinessPage.java and two separate class files for components header and footer, Header.java and Footer.java. These files are in separate package than page class files. My test class file is TestCaseDevelopment.java and base class is TestBase.java. I need to access header link 'enroll' (whose locator is in Header.java file) from Test class TestCaseDevelopment.java using HomePage object. (HomePage contain HeaderHomePage locator which finds whole header on the web page. LinkEnroll locator in Header.java file locates link in the header. so complete locator for the link is HeaderHomePage+LinkEnroll, means `//header//div[@id='masthead']//a[normalize-space()='Enroll']` which I am not able to access it.

I don't want to create duplicates for Header and footer in every page class file. How do I define these sections as a separate class files and include them  in to my page class files?

HomePage.java

```
public class HomePage extends TestBase {

    @FindBy(xpath = "//header//div[@id='masthead']")
    public Header HeaderHomePage;

    public HomePage() {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }
}
```

SmallBusinessPage.java

```
public class SmallBusinessPage extends TestBase{

    @FindBy(xpath = "//header//div[@id='masthead']")
    public Header HeaderSmallBusiness;

    public SmallBusinessPage() {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }
}
```

Header

```
public class Header extends TestBase{

    @FindBy(xpath="//a[normalize-space()='Enroll']")
    WebElement LinkEnroll;

    public Header() {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }
}
```

Footer

```
public class Footer extends TestBase {

    @FindBy(xpath="//footer//a[text()='Careers']")
    public WebElement LinkCareers;

    public Footer() {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }
}
```

TestBase

```
public class TestBase {

    public static WebDriver driver;
    public static Properties prop;
    Header header = new Header();

    public TestBase(){

        try {
            prop = new Properties();
            FileInputStream istream = new FileInputStream("C:\\QA -Selenium\\WS\\WellsFargoTest\\src\\main\\java\\com\\wellsfargo\\qa\\config\\config.properties");
            prop.load(istream);
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void initialization() {
        String browserName = prop.getProperty("browser");
        if(browserName.equals("chrome")){
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Selenium\\chromedriver");
            driver =new ChromeDriver();
        }
        if(browserName.equals("FF")){
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Selenium\\geckodriver");
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        }
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(TestUtility.PAGE_LOAD_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);        
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(TestUtility.IMLICIT_WAIT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);  
        driver.get(prop.getProperty("url"));
    }
}
```

TestCaseDevelopment

```
public class TestCaseDevelopment extends TestBase{

    HomePage homePage;
    public TestCaseDevelopment() {
        super();
    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setup() {
        initialization();
        homePage = new HomePage();
        ****homePage.HeaderHomePage.l****
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per standard practice you have to create single class called `BaesPage.java` which keep all common locators across the application. All page object will extend this class so all common locators will available for   All page objects. Please have a look.

**BasePage.java**

```
public class BasePage{

    @FindBy(xpath="//a[normalize-space()='Enroll']")
    WebElement LinkEnroll;


@FindBy(xpath="//footer//a[text()='Careers']")
    public WebElement LinkCareers;

    public BasePage() {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }
public void clickEnroll()
{

LinkEnroll.click();
}
}
```

> Now you don’t need Header.java and Footer.java two separate classes as
>   both have common locators across application so it is moved in
>   BasePage.java

**HomePage.java**

```
public class HomePage extends BasePage {

    @FindBy(xpath = "//header//div[@id='masthead']")
    public Header HeaderHomePage;

    public HomePage() {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }
}
```

**TestBase.java**

```
public class TestBase {

    public static WebDriver driver;
    public static Properties prop;
    Header header = new Header();

    public TestBase(){

        try {
            prop = new Properties();
            FileInputStream istream = new FileInputStream("C:\\QA -Selenium\\WS\\WellsFargoTest\\src\\main\\java\\com\\wellsfargo\\qa\\config\\config.properties");
            prop.load(istream);
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void initialization() {
        String browserName = prop.getProperty("browser");
        if(browserName.equals("chrome")){
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Selenium\\chromedriver");
            driver =new ChromeDriver();
        }
        if(browserName.equals("FF")){
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Selenium\\geckodriver");
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        }
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(TestUtility.PAGE_LOAD_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);        
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(TestUtility.IMLICIT_WAIT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);  
        driver.get(prop.getProperty("url"));
    }
}
```

**TestCaseDevelopment**

```
public class TestCaseDevelopment extends TestBase{

    HomePage homePage;
    public TestCaseDevelopment() {
        super();
    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setup() {
        initialization();
        homePage = new HomePage();
//Now you can call clickEnroll from any page object
        homePage.clickEnroll();
    }
}
```